# Start Emacs with entering gdb mi mode (NOT after startup and enter gdb mi manually)

Tags: start-up, gdb

How do I start emacs with a command and its option, for example, I want emacs start with entering gdb mi mode, otherwise it does not go to the gdb mode during startup.

The following works:

```
emacs gdb
```

Or using evaluate:

```
emacs gdb -e gdb
```

But I want to enter the mi mode and this does not work:

```
emacs gdb -i=mi
```

Or this:

```
emacs -e gdb -i=mi
```

Unfortunately I just want to enter mi mode directly during startup.

Comment: Use a `.emacs` file or `init.el` file and customize it, or learn how to pass arguments from the command line that include `elisp`.  If you do a bit of Googling, you will find a zillion hits.  E.g., **Evaluate emacs lisp expession on command line** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474774/evaluate-emacs-lisp-expession-on-command-line

Comment: I want to enter gdb mi mode on startup not after startup to enter gdb mi manually

Comment: @lawlist But how can I also include -i=mi, evaluate does not work on that but I really need to enter the text gui mode during startup.

Comment: The following link has an example that you can work with and modify as needed:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577536/gdb-in-emacs-24-messed-up  You should be using Emacs 25 at this point unless there is a good reason for using an earlier version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
emacs --eval "(gdb \"gdb -i=mi\")"
```

Comment: Using simple quotes removes the need for backslash escapes. Also, you can include executable name in that command  `emacs --eval '(gdb "gdb -i=mi ./myexecutable")' &` . You might be interested also in `-x` option of gdb that starts a specific script. Or include `source localgdbscript` in your `~/.gdbinit` so that a `localgdbscript` in your local directory is automatically run.